Could a Bronze age era world build a arch bridge to cross a Thames-sized river?
My world is set in a mid-late bronze age world, I was wondering if people of that time would be able to build a long arch bridge to cross a river that is similar to the Thames in width. I know the longest bridge we have left from that time period is only 30 meters long, but in my opinion, civilizations that were able to build pyramids up to 146 meters tall and massive ziggurats would probably be able to build something longer and grander than that.

How deep is that river? How large is the community building the bridge? What kind of materials do they have access to?

Must it be a single-arch bridge? Given enough people with shovels, it wouldn't be that hard to divert the river, built a stone multi-span bridge, then let the river return to its original course. Bronze-age people could do that.

Greetings Pico! For future reference, "can it be done" questions like this really do require you to pay attention to details before posting! In order to give a reasonable answer that will help you with your project, we'd need to know what counts as "bronze age" in your world, how advanced are they mathematically, socially, technologically. We'd need to know what size river you'd like to span, what materials are available, etc. We do have a Sandbox where you can learn how to write good questions!

When you say Thames-sized, do you mean the Thames now or as it was in the Bronze age? (It was much wider and surrounded by somewhat marshy ground.)

Where exactly on the Thames are you asking about creating a bridge? The width of the river will have a massive impact about whether building a single span stone arch bridge is possible or not. Are you even asking about single span bridges or is a multi span bridge acceptable?

this is trivially technically possible if extremely costly, when compared to other things Bronze Age civilizations did. The problem is WHY? This would be a major investment, of time, calories, and political effort, that would need a really good justification for this. A bridge could be made cheapely out of a dozen smaller spans, or out of wooden floating pallets, or even use a rope-ferry. A single-span bridge with Bronze Age technology, is an equivalent of a billion dollar investment in modern terms. How does it pay for itself?

Ever heard of the Roman-era Bridge near Limyra?

Bronze-age communities certainly knew how to build ferry boats or to procure the craft to build them; if asked to build a long bridge, the natural move is to start from that and build a pontoon bridge. Why would you have them bother about arch bridges specifically?

Of course they could build it if they knew how to. Building a bridge requires real engineering skill, unlike just piling up stones (for a pyramid) or bricks (for a ziggurat). A pyramid or a ziggurat is what you build when you have no idea of how to compute the required strength of the supports needed to hold up a given weight -- you just pile them up and the result is a massive heap of stones or bricks.
In the real history bronze age, they did not know how to build stone bridges over rivers, but in the fictional world it depends on what you the author want them to know. Roman stone bridges did not use iron, so that if the people in the fictional world have the required level of engineering skill then they can do it.
P.S. The Romans did built a bridge over the Thames at Londinium, but it was made of wood not stone.

Knowledge of the arch dates back clear to the stone age, it simply wasn't used much (the related corbel arch is easier to build and nearly as useful).

A Bronze Age civilisation could build an arch-bridge of that kind, they had the know how. The problem of course, is that it would be insanely expensive when it comes to labor, food, materials, money (as they were) and political will. I cannot see this making economic sense unless the bridge-building empire is already stupidly rich, or there is some  heavy and hard to transport source of wealth on the other side of the river, that HAS TO be transported across the river, for some reason, rather than along it.

It would likely be cheaper to transport things along the river then along the shores of the continent to whenever it needs to go, for a 1000 years, over and over, than build the bridge.

@GoingDurden: You are aware of course that the Roman built lots and lots of bridges, over all kinds of rivers. What you may not know is that by modern standarfds taxes were absurdly low; the one thing that the Roman empire wasn't is rich. Yes, there were lots of rich people and quite a few rich cities, but the state itself was never particularly rich. It was a very different world than ours; rich individuals and rich local collectivities were socially expected to leave behind something durable.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar%27s_Rhine_bridges     not Bronze age, but it gives some indication of what can be achieved with very primitive technology 140-400m length wooden bridge built across the river Rhine (up to 9m depth). In 10 days.

Aqueducts might work.
I would say building a stone structure (like the towers of the tower bridge, just less ornated) is not the problem, given the pyramids you mentioned.
More problematic is the suspension "cables". There is no steel, and copper-wire or bronze for that matter seems to be too weak to withstand the weight it has to hold. Also it would oxidize on air, weakening it further, probably. Also rope would be to weak and maintenance very hard to realize, I assume.
Now, suspension bridges are not the only form of bridges. They might be able to pull off something like an aqueduct, the romans used for transporting water.

The question explicitly specifies an arch bridge, the only kind of bridge people built out of stone or brick for thousands of years. Suspension bridges are a very modern invention. Like this bridge over the Guadiana River at Mérida in southwest Spain, built by the Roman emperor Trajan 1900 years ago and still in use.

Please note, that I am not suggesting a suspension bridge, tho. It is only an intermediate thought. Your example seems to fit perfectly! Nice find.

Not a bridge but this shows what can be done. The tunnel under the Euphrates was almost 1 Km long and built in about 50 BCE. We do not have physical remains, but the accounts of its construction - diverting the river, cut-and-cover, restoring the river - sound believable. Babylon was not Bronze Age, but the the construction used stone sealed with bitumen, so no iron was needed.
Why would they build your bridge? I think if there was enough need, and given strong leadership, a bronze Age state could build a long bridge. However, rivers were natural lines of defence. Bridges were often designed to be dismantled or destroyed in case of invasion.
Why was the Euphrates tunnel built at all? Perhaps the Euphrates was not deep enough for defence, so the tunnel did not present a risk (and it could be flooded if it did). It would be a marvellous in-yer-face piece of technology to impress visitors.

Your chronology is way off, and the tunnel is as legendary as the suspended gardens of Babylon. It is Diodore of Sicily who lived in the 1st century BCE. He attributes the tunnel to Queen Semiramis, which is the default go-to attribution for wondrous stuff in Mesopotamia. A possible prototype for Semiramis is Queen Shammuramat of the Assyrian Empire, who lived in the 9th century BCE, 800 years before Diodore of Sicily. Unfortunately she did not build any suspended gardens or tunnels under the Euphrates.

Yes and no. It had been possible technologically.
Not because they did not have the knowledge, and probably they did not have the population.
The knowledge to build such huge structures was not known at the time, but if they had known it, they could have built it.
Very likely, it had not been only a single arch. Instead, they had many pylons, roughly so:

Very likely, the work had been extraordinary for them - note, their largest problem, and also their "birth controller" was that the land could keep only a small amount of people with the eyes of the today. The rest has died, mostly in various sicknesses, in their early childhood. Their life was really, really nightmarish with the eye of the today. It is quite unlikely that you would think on bridge building with their mindset.
Either you need some large, well-organised civilization, which is unlikely in the stone age, or you need some - most likely, religious - objective to keep them working on this project, instead of working on to get food to their hungry children.(*)
(*) The people of the ancient Egypt did not need this choice. They worked in synchron with the Nyle, and they had some months in the year where there was no work and also no grain. So they needed a civilization which shares the grain for these bad months, and also it gives them work, to prevent them from thinking about government changes :-) . But that was a rare coincide even in the bronze age. No large stone age civilization is known.
